# How to not use ScientificStyle with CGFloat?

Tags: ios, swift2

I want to convert a String to CGFloat but because of the String is too long, the converted number is formatted with the ScientificStyle.

How can I avoid this?

The one I want: **10153414864354680**

The one I get: **1.01534148643547e+16**

**Code**

```
CGFloat(NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(str)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The converted number (i.e., the `CGFloat`) does not have a style.  You only see the style when you print it or otherwise try and display it and it implicitly converts it into a `String`.  You should use an `NSNumberFormatter` to convert it back to a `String` to display.

```
print("Value: \(NSNumberFormatter().stringFromNumber(<#Some CGFloat#>))")
```

Comment: I understand, thank you for your response. I thought it had an inherited format. Have a nice day.